# making files in the folder donwloadable using php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to making files to be downloadable after clicking the link of the listed file. I am not getting idea how to make it possible. I have completed to list file using following scripts. Now I have to provide listed file to be downloadable after clicking the file name. Plz help...

```
$dir = 'd:/temp_file/voice/';
if (is_dir($dir)) {
 if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
        echo "filename: ".$file."<br />";
               // header('Content-type: audio/wav');

             //   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dir.$file.'"');

              //  readfile($dir.$file);
    }
    closedir($dh);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Files are already downloadable by default.

Create a php file, through which the file will be downloaded. For example: `download.php` Place the following codes on them.

```
 $filename = $_GET['filename']; 
 $dir = "../path/to/directory/"; //$dir = 'd:/temp_file/voice/';
 // ^ Use Relative links           ^ Not system dependent link as this
 if(is_file($dir.$filename)) {
    header('Content-type: audio/wav');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dir.$file.'"');
    echo file_get_contents($dir.$file);
 }
```

Next link to this page as this

```
<a href="download.php?name=filename.jpg">Download FileName</a>
```

Comment: That's going to send a ton of headers and the content of every file in the directory.  Also, you need to wrap the header and file_get_contents in {} (the if needs {}).

Comment: It doesn't works, the file is downloaded which not available in folder that have another name.Here the file is downloaded immediately visiting the links. After all,I have to download the file after clicking the listed file link.

Comment: @Corbin, I just copied OP's code, assuming it would be correct.

Comment: this code works only when wav file and download.php files are in same folder. When tried for path stored in $dir in above code, the downloaded file name looks like d_temp_file_wavfilename.wav. It seems header function doesn't accept d:/temp_file/voice/

Comment: I think only certain file types are downloadable by default, quite a few will open in the browser rather than download when clicked.

Comment: I have solved problems. if We eliminate the $dir in header function in above code, it works.. Thanks starx

Comment: @TobyAllen, even to be show in the browser, they have to downloaded first. It is different point that user does not have to initiate the process.

Comment: @ShresthaSunil, Its a really bad idea to include fixed links like that, specially `C, D` drives are for windows only. what if user browses the website from a linux machine, so use relative path, like shown in my updated answer.

Comment: File name should be sanitized. And the server determines OS PHP runs on, not the browser?  That last comment made no sense. (Well it did if he's trying to pass a local path and not one on the server. Either way, I agree, he should be using relative paths, just not sure what your last comment meant.)